# make file issue : always spits out "Nothing to be done for `make.w'."

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

I have 3 files Head.cpp , Head.h and Hello.cpp . I am trying to build a make for the compilation process. My makefile is make.w

```
Hello :   Head.o Hello.o
          g++ -o Head.o Hello.o

Head.o :  Head.cpp
          g++ -o Head.cpp

Hello.o:  Hello.cpp
          g++ -o Hello.cpp
```

every time I type the command make make.w - I get " Nothing to make fot make.w" . I dont get why this is happening and how to resolve the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are calling the `make` with a non-default make file which is `makefile` or `Makefile` you need to use the `-f` option as:

```
make -f make.w
     ^^
```

Looks like you are currently calling it as:

```
make make.w
```

which does not work. It tell `make` to make the ***target*** `make.w` in the default makefile.

Also When converting from `.c` to `.o` you need to use the `-c` compiler flag which tells the compiler to just compile ***but don't link***. Also when using `-c` you don't need `-o`, the compiler will generate the `<filename>.o` for you.

```
Head.o :  Head.cpp
          g++ -c  Head.cpp
              ^^

Hello.o:  Hello.cpp
          g++ -c  Hello.cpp
              ^^
```

And finally you are missing the name of the executable `Hello` on the compile line:

```
Hello :   Head.o Hello.o
          g++ -o Head Head.o Hello.o
                 ^^^^
```

Comment: Now, I get an ` make -f mkfl.w
g++ -o Head Head.cpp
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.3.1/../../../../lib/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Head.o] Error 1` error

Comment: I've updated the answer, you need to use `-o` option as shown.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to compile it after making changes and get the following error 
g++ -c -o Head Head.cpp
g++ -c -o Hello Hello.cpp
g++ -c -o Head.o Hello.o
g++: Hello.o: No such file or directory
g++: no input files
make: *** [ram] Error 1

Comment: I've updated my answer. You don't need the `-o` option, just use `-c`.

Comment: Thanks, helps a lot. Also I am looking for good tutorials to build shared and static libraries. Do you suggest reading any particular articles?

Answer (score 2):

`make make.w` means "Make target `make.w` in default makefile named `Makefile`".

You want to specify your makefile, so you want `make -f make.w`

Answer (score 1):

You need a -f in front of the makefile name.

```
make -f make.w
```

You may want to specify the target to be built as well

```
make -f make.w Hello
```